# Sorting dictionary by key value using standard approach not working

Tags: python

The line where I am creating the "sorted" dictionary it is giving me as error:

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

However, this method of sorting a dictionary seems to be a pretty standard way of doing it and cannot see why this would not work?

```
word_counts = {'positive': {},
                'neutral': {},
                'negative': {}}

for idx, sentence in enumerate(df_norm['Full Text']):
    for word in sentence:
        if word in word_counts[df_norm['Sentiment'][idx]].keys():
            word_counts[df_norm['Sentiment'][idx]][word] += 1
        else:
            word_counts[df_norm['Sentiment'][idx]][word] = 1

sorted = dict(sorted(word_counts['positive'].items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
print(sorted)
```

Comment: Don't call your variable `sorted`. That stomps on the `sorted()` builtin function you just called.

Comment: thank you I have applied that change. However, still does not work :(

Comment: (In fact, that might be your issue. Are you running this in an interactive session, e.g. a Jupyter notebook? If you've already run this code, `sorted` becomes a dictionary. If you try to call `sorted()` again, you get the dictionary, not the function.)

Comment: Well spotted! `del sorted` fixed it.